# Optimize python Code to get result very quick

Tags: python, pandas

I would to optimize my code

I am trying to create new row from my DataFrame previous value by changing only a value of the Column 'Value' and keeping the value of other column.

I do not know if doing this is good "`tmp_df[:1]['Value']`"  cause for many data it takes long time.

I have only found this way. If you have an Idea for optimisation:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'WorkerId': [1, 2] ,'Value': [3, 4,],'WeekDay':['a','b']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


Listweek=['a','b'] #my week list 
WorkerIdList=[1,2] # my worker ID

#creating a DataFrame with the same column name as df
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns) 


for workerid in WorkerIdList:
    for week in Listweek:

            if(not df[ (df.WeekDay==week)].empty):   

                # I am taking the first row because I want to keep some value
                tmp_df=df[ (df.WeekDay==week)][:1]  

                #Then I change a the value on the column "Value"
                tmp_df[:1]['Value']= df[(df['WorkerId']==workerid)]['Value'].iloc[0] + random.randint(1, 10) 

                #I am doing concatenation
                frames = [df2, tmp_df[:1]]
                df2 = pd.concat(frames)
df2
```

output: [image]

Comment: The question is not very clear to me, can you explain in words?

Answer (score 0):

as it is not clear what you want exactly only thing i can give you is

```
df2=df.copy() 
df2.Value=df2.Value+random.randint(1,10)
```

will give similar result without declaration of

```
Listweek=['a','b'] #my week list 


WorkerIdList=[1,2] # my worker ID
```